# PostgreSQL stored procedure to insert data error

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table in PostgreSQL

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sse_schema.customer
(
    customer_id varchar(3) NOT NULL, 
    customer_Sname varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    customer_Fname varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    customer_address varchar(150),
    phone_number varchar (15),
    dob date,
    bank_name varchar(30),
    bank_address varchar(150),
    bank_sortcode varchar(8),
    account_no integer,
    PRIMARY KEY (customer_id)
)
```

I want to create stored procedure to insert data into the table with the code below using stored procedure

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sse_schema.register_newcustomer(customer_id varchar(3), customer_Sname varchar(20),customer_Fname varchar(20), customer_address varchar(150),phone_number varchar (15),dob date,bank_name varchar(30),bank_address varchar(150),bank_sortcode varchar(8),account_no integer)
AS $$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO customer (customer_id,customer_Sname,customer_Fname,customer_address,phone_number,dob,bank_name,bank_address,bank_sortcode,account_number)
  VALUES(customer_id,customer_Sname,customer_Fname,customer_address,phone_number,dob,bank_name,bank_address,bank_sortcode,account_number);
 
 
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CALL customer('s12',James','Fast','12 ways','07988654564','2022-12-07','HSBC','35 bank way M8 3AB','040021',10204312)
```

When I call the procedure it gives the error below

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Fast"
LINE 1: CALL customer('s12',James','Fast','12 ways','07988654564','2...
                                    ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 29
```

Comment: [As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html)  INSERT needs a `VALUES` clause

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name How can I do It with insert value? Thanks

Comment: INSERT INTO customer(....) VALUES(....), just like you would do without the procedure. You don't need the plpgsql for this simple procedure either, SQL would be good enough.

Comment: @FrankHeikens I have been able to create it but when I call it it gives error. I have modify my question to reflect the current error msg

Comment: Add VALUES keyword in your query `INSERT INTO customer VALUES (customer_id,customer_Sname,customer_Fname,customer_address,phone_number,dob,bank_name,bank_address,bank_sortcode,account_number);` and also remove `LANGUAGE plpgsql;` because there is no need for plpgsql for simple queries

Comment: You're missing a quote ' before the value 'James'.

Comment: @maddy23285 when I remove LANGUAGE plpgsql; from the proc it give error when I try to create it

Comment: You have to write a valid SQL function, without BEGIN and END; and of course LANGUAGE SQL. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html